# Minus sign too long

Tags: math-mode, arev

The minus sign in `arevmath` is too long. In particular, it is longer than the plus sign. Is there a way to correct this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% \DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignC}{OMS}{zavm}{m}{n}
% \DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathrel}{mathdesignC}{"01}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|@{}l@{}|}
  $+$\\
  \color{red}$-$\\
  $\pm$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt

\sbox0{$+$}\the\wd0\fbox{\box0}

\sbox0{$-$}\the\wd0\fbox{\box0}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$-$}$+$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$+$}$-$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as you see, the bounding boxes have the same width.

What can we do? We might horizontally scale the minus sign (exploiting the rectangular shape) but keep the original width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % always do it for math

\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\scaledarevminus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\scaledarevminus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\scaledarevminus@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\std@minus$}%
  \makebox[\wd\z@]{\kern-0.01\wd\z@\scalebox{0.85}[1]{\usebox\z@}}%
  \endgroup
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\scaledarevminus
  \mathcode`-="8000
}
\def\newmcodes@{% fix the amsopn.sty definition
  \mathcode`\'39 \mathcode`\*42 \mathcode`\."613A
  \mathcode`\-45\mathcode`\/47\mathcode`\:"603A
  \relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt
\sbox0{$+$}\the\wd0\fbox{\box0}
\sbox0{$-$}\the\wd0\fbox{\box0}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$-$}$+$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$+$}\textcolor{red}{$-$}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$\scriptstyle -$}$\scriptstyle +$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\scriptstyle +$}\textcolor{red}{$\scriptstyle -$}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$\scriptscriptstyle -$}$\scriptscriptstyle +$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\scriptscriptstyle +$}\textcolor{red}{$\scriptscriptstyle -$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A zoomed version

[image]

The symbols are placed asymmetrically in their bounding box, but that's a choice of the font designer. But we can fix also that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % always do it for math

\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\std@plus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\scaledarevminus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\scaledarevminus@\relax}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\movedarevplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\movedarevplus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\scaledarevminus@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\std@minus$}%
  \makebox[\wd\z@]{\kern0.06\wd\z@\scalebox{0.85}[1]{\usebox\z@}}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\movedarevplus@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\std@plus$}%
  \makebox[\wd\z@]{\kern0.07\wd\z@\usebox\z@}%
  \endgroup
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\scaledarevminus
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`+\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\movedarevplus
  \mathcode`-="8000
  \mathcode`+="8000
}

\def\newmcodes@{% fix the amsopn.sty definition
  \mathcode`\'39 \mathcode`\*42 \mathcode`\."613A
  \mathcode`\-45\mathcode`\/47\mathcode`\:"603A
  \relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=0.1pt
\sbox0{$+$}\the\wd0\fbox{\box0}
\sbox0{$-$}\the\wd0\fbox{\box0}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$-$}$+$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$+$}\textcolor{red}{$-$}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$\scriptstyle -$}$\scriptstyle +$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\scriptstyle +$}\textcolor{red}{$\scriptstyle -$}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$\scriptscriptstyle -$}$\scriptscriptstyle +$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\scriptscriptstyle +$}\textcolor{red}{$\scriptscriptstyle -$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could be useful to add your patch to `\newmcodes@` to your second solution. Thanks again for all. Works like a charm

Comment: @user94293 done, thanks for asking to